# Angular routing to components as child routes imported from Shared Module

Tags: angular, routes, children

I have menu component in shared module and the menu component should navigate to components like faq, about, etc., which are alo in shared module. I need to navigate to them from configurator module where the shared module imported is.
My routes in configurator module looks like this:

[Configurator routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oG2c.png)

My try to do this is here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCPgy.png)

but it does have no effect an I'm getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mKLf.png)

I'm junior developer, so for every advice, help or enhancement, I would be very grateful. And sorry for my English of course, I'm not native speaker.

Comment: Hey, Remove '../' from the navigate just add about route name.

Comment: Please do use the code block and not images. Make it much easier for us look at instead of clicking on images.

Comment: Jany, create a demo example on stackblitz.com and let me know in the comment section. that would help you and us as well so that we can create a live example. through that we can improve your coding practice as well

Comment: @ShashankVivek this demo should represent my problem [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xlxvwr) actually what i need is that when i clicked on about, i need to show the content in router outlet named 'menu', when I click configurator, i dont want to reload only hide the item in router outlet a change the url, as u see, I want also to navigate to about screen from home component

Comment: Can you explain this better : `when I click configurator, i dont want to reload only hide the **item in router outlet** a change the url` ? which router-outlet are we talking abt here ?

Comment: router-outlet named menu in main component